# Restarting Threads in python and checking for exceptions

Tags: python, multithreading, cherrypy, python-multithreading

I have drawn out a flowchart of a process I would like to follow, but cannot figure out how to carry this out.  At the moment I have the following.

t1 is a database insertion script not cherrypy.

```
def main():
    thread = ThreadUrl(queue)
    thread = thread()
    thread.start()
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
                            'server.socket_port': 2970})
                            #'server.thread_pool': 100})
    queue.join()
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    while True:
        if thread.isAlive():
            try:
                cherrypy.engine.start()
            except Exception:
                print ('Started cherrypy already.')
            print ('I am alive.')
        else:
            try:
                thread.exit()
            except Exception:
                print ('Already killed this thread.')
            print ('I am dead.')
            try:
                cherrypy.engine.stop()
            except Exception:
                print ('Already stopped cherrypy.')
            try:
                thread.start()
            except Exception:
                print (sys.exc_info()[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: I would like to follow this flow chart]

Comment: That seems...a bit convoluted, given that `cherrypy.engine` already implements its own state machine, and only blocks the calling thread if you call `cherrypy.engine.block()`. What are you trying to accomplish with the wrapper thread?

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to add a line in the description that was kinda important, t1 is a database insertion script not cherrypy.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a state table in a dict. Each node would be in a function which performs its action and then returns the next state, something like this:

```
def start_t1():
    # Start t1.
    return "start cherrypy"

def start_cherrypy():
    # Start Cherrypy.
    return "is t1 alive?"

def is_cherrypy_alive():
    # Check whether Cherrypy is alive.
    if alive:
        return "stop cherrypy"
    return "start t1"

actions = {
    "start t1": start_t1,
    "start cherrypy": start_cherrypy,
    "is t1 alive?": is_t1_alive,
    "is cherry pie alive?": is_cherrypy_alive,
    ...
}

state = "start t1"
while True:
    state = actions[state]()
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to add a line in the description that was kinda important, t1 is a database insertion script not cherrypy.